# bIII upon bII5, bII7#11omit3, how to name that chord in this context?

Tags: chord-theory, analysis

*Note : I had trouble to name this question properly. I would've gone with "What's that chord name" but it doesn't seem to help anyone that would stumble across a similar problem to find my question. Anyway, my question seem to be very specific.*

**Context** : I'm pretty new to music theory I'm trying to analyse the music "Rude Buster" from Deltarune OST ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQCZbccqE7s)), and so far I'm slowly making progress in understanding the piece, which is nice :) Though, there's a part where I struggle to find the adequate way to analyse it.

[image]

The piece is in F#minor. In the first half of bar 1 & 3, the crazy bass highlights an `F#5`, which goes well with the chord part that does an `A major`, creating a `F#m7`. Then, in the second half of the measures, it goes to highlighting a weird `G5`  chord when the chord section stay on `A major` (except for the last one of the bar which is an inversion of `F#m`).

The result is creating some kind of polychord, `A upon G5`, or `bIII upon bII5`, in relative, assuming that I got the key right.

**My problem** : The thing is, I can't really make a link between what I hear and what I can analyze out of it, because I've never encountered such a weird combination of notes. Since I can't really put a name on it, I guessed that it should sound dissonant, but it doesn't really to me.

**My guesses** :

- My first guess was just saying that the bass is crazy anyway and "has the right to" (=can without sounding too dissonant) spend half of a measure playing some crazy notes. But it doesn't match it's behavior for the rest of the piece. For the rest, I've figured it did quite a good job playing the chord tones (while often supplementing the fondamental) and while using some passing tones here and there.
- Another guess would be that a B is implicit, making this chord `G7#11` (with the 9, `A`). This make more sense to why this chord doesn't sound that dissonant to me. So I would be tempted to treat it as a `G7#11omit3`, in relative a `bII7#11omit3`, borrowed from the parallel phrygian I guess ?

I like the second one, but I'll gladly hear what you have to say on it.

EDIT : Actually my second guess can't be totally accurate, as I did not include the `E` of the `A major` chord, also the `13` of `G`. And there's no 7 in that chord either. So it would be a glorious `G13(#11)omit3omit7`, in relative a `bII13(#11)omit3omit7` ? Pretty crazy chord right here !

Comment: Interesting ! The bass does stand out a lot in this piece, though could you call the A an ostinato, when it's only been played two times before, half a measure at a fast tempo ? I get the idea though, it's kinda related to what I was trying to say in my first guess :)

Comment: My mistake--turns out that the OP's excerpt is from the very beginning of the piece, but the bassline is isolated as its own very prominent entity later. I'm a fan of treating the chords and bassline as separate entities in this case.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I understand. Though I got some interesting insights from analysing it as a whole, since together they were forming some 7 chords that I thought fitted better to what I hear in the piece. Except here, where they form this massive weird chord :D
But yeah, I see the point in analysing it separately. EDIT : Ok I've misread your comment as well, so in this part you don't necessarly think it's a good thing to treat them separately ? Right.

Answer (score 1):

The chord, from your description, highlights G and D in the bass, and has A, C♯, and E in the upper structure. I have not listened to the song, but from these notes, to me there are at least **two distinct possibilities**.

Your **polychord analysis** was my first instinct, seeing the upper structure and the lower component. A/G5 would be equivalent to the tertian quality G(9♯11), omitting the third (which seems reasonable enough, since B is much more likely than Bb here). If we truly are in the key of F♯ minor (A major was my first instinct - mixolydian is a pretty common choice for modal mixture, but then again this is VGM, so phrygian's not out of the picture by any means), then this chord is built on the ♭II scale degree. This could very well be a **tritone substitution** for the dominant chord C♯ in a jazz-based context, or **modal mixture** (hence your phrygian explanation) or a **Neapolitan 6th**, depending heavily on context and style.

However, there's another explanation that may have merit. You mention some earlier examples of the A chord appearing in the upper structure with a bass structure outside of that chord. It is very possible to me that this G power chord idea is simply a move upwards from F♯ to G along the phrygian scale, while the A chord is somewhat dronelike in that it holds over in seeming defiance of the bassline for effect. This would make a lot of sense if the bass outlined, say, F♯5, then G5, then A5. I think that it's probably a good idea to **view the bass and chords as being separate entities** in this case, and it may be the case in your example as well.

And of course, it's always possible that neither A nor G are the root of the chord and this is some nasty inversion, but that's unlikely, and I think you probably would have picked up on that.

Comment: Very interesting insights ! And a lot of vocabulary, some terms I need to go look for them since I don't know them yet, which is a very good occasion to learn new terms. Give me time to look these terms and I'll come back with an answer :)
Have you seen my edit ? It seems you were redacting your answer while I did my edit. I think you did a mistake when saying that we have the maj7 in the chord, since we don't have any F# in this chord. So, in tertian, it would actually be a `G13(#11)omit3omit7`... that's a lot of omissions there !

Comment: @021 Good catch - no major seventh. Let me fix that...

Comment: Either I'm mistaken myself, but I believe there are still some mistakes in the second paragraph : `G(9♯11), omitting the third (which seems reasonable enough, since we have the major seventh)` still says we have the major seventh, and doesn't include the 13 (or 6) (E)

Comment: @021 Thanks. In the future, you can just propose an edit if you see something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As you say your pretty new to music theory ...

- you shouldn’t start analyzing chords like these crazy chords
- don’t choose a notation with errors
- don’t try to transfer or adapt the RN. to a harmony        that isn’t written in this music language and doesn’t fit in this system.

the simple analysis is:

A/f#m, A/G ... etc. we can be pleased understanding this construction. More interpretation isn’t appropriate to this chords or this progression.

G isn’t N6 of F#m. A isn’t bIII,  while the bass note F (natural) should be E#.

of course we can say A/G is G7911 ... but what have we won?

Comment: Uh... OP does say they're new to music theory, but to me, anyone who can handle extended chord naming and polychords can handle roman numeral analysis. I completely missed OP even saying that in the first place, because their post was written quite intelligently.

Comment: Some questions : 
- What are the errors on the notation ? The way the natural symbols are handled ? Because of the natural F instead of E# ? - What is RN ? - Why A isn't bIII ?

Comment: I prefer to avoid using polychords for my analysis because they're not very meaningful for me for right now. I can't really put a sound on `A upon G5` but I kinda can on `G13(#11)omit3omit7`, since in this notation it highlights the link between this chord and a G13(#11), even though some notes are missing, it induces that they might be implicitly heard by a listener. Then again, maybe I just lack the knowledge to put a sound on `A upon G5`, and if you and other person say that it's more meaningful this way, I'll take it ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it complicated? This is just the third inversion of a plain A7 chord (A7/G). The D is melodic in the context of the root/fifth bass line and not harmonically relevant here, and even if it was, you could interpret it as the bass of a Dmaj9 chord (missing the 3rd).